# Can you please identify this type of jQuery Slider?

Tags: jquery

I have asked this question on many forums, with no joy at all.

Its like a  stepped or range sliders, that you can drag the pointer along, with snap to easing animation to anyone of the points on the slider.

Obviously it looks like a UI slider, thats customised, but what I want to know is "whats the actual name of this type of slider" so I can try and create one.

[image]

If it is just a UI Slider. with incremental steps, then thats great, could you "aside from jquery" demos, give me any links to online code, demos etc, where there are similar sliders with "SNAP TO" points.

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried the jQuery UI with "Snap to increments" demo ? Doesn't that work for you? (http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#steps) You'll only need to change the layout

Comment: @OP [RTFG](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+snapto)

Comment: I hadnt seen stepped version, must be going blind.

Comment: Here we go again voting down, must be wonderful being perfect.

Comment: It's a perfectly valid question. +1 to negate the -1

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how hard you have looked. A search from google "jquery snapto" resulted in several seemingly good resources. Of them,

- The jquery demo, the last one "I only snap to an 80x80 grid" may interest you

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/snap-to.html

- The example and documentation for draggable at jquery

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

- The documentation for snapto at jquery

http://ui-dev.jquery.com/demos/draggable/#snap-to

Comment: Hey travis ty, i hadnt googled snapto, that was just a wild description when i madethis post. Ty for the links, sincerely appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

The name of that type of control element is an input element of [type range](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#range-state-%28type=range%29). As for that specific customization of the element, you'd need to look at the source code to determine if it is public code (i.e. a third party jQuery plugin) or something written by the site developer. If it's the former, then there should at least be a license header with information that can help identify it.

Comment: Hi, the slider i screenpicced. The guy as removed all attributions, even for jquery. Will check link thankyou. Link to originl http://online-audio-converter.com/

Answer (score 0):

These slider was done manually. I've found no jQuery plugins that implement such functionality, so I had to develop my own solution using jQuery.UI draggable.  I'm the developer of that site )

Comment: Well you did a great job, the nearest I have found madsnow is a timeline slider. How did you accomplish FILL as the slider was dragged ?

Comment: Two divs with different background-images. One div excat above another. And while dragging just change the width of above div.